# Attribute value must be constant: @RequestMapping, java spring endpoint

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, annotations

Currently I am trying to reduce the boilerplate in my java spring controllers by creating an interface  `CRUDRestController`, which creates a common set of default endpoints:

```
interface CRUDRestController<T, Key extends Serializable> {

     //...

     String getEndpoint();

     @RequestMapping(value = getEndpoint() + "/{key}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     default T get(@PathVariable("key") String key) {
          return getRepository().findOne(stringToKey(key));
     }

     //...
}
```

The problem is that the above code does not compile since `value = getEndpoint() + "/{key}"` is supposedly not a compile time constant. In reality every controller's implementation of `getEndpoint()` is something like this:

```
@Override
public String getEndpoint() {
    return "/clients";
}
```

This is clearly known at compile time, however I have no way of telling this to spring. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that will help you:

```
interface CRUDRestController<T, Key extends Serializable> {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/{key}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     default T get(@PathVariable("key") String key) {
          return getRepository().findOne(stringToKey(key));
     }
}
```

and the implementation:

```
@RequestMapping("/clients")
public class ClientController implements CRUDRestController<Client, ClientKey> {

//...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java annotations restriction. All values passed to it must be compile time constants.
The value is clearly not known at compile time even if you would call a static method returning a static final.

Comment: Is there no other way create a generic controller then? Right now I have a bunch of classes which all share pretty much exactly the same code.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that there are certain URLs like /bar/x and /foo/x i.e.both sharing the same key.

Comment: What you want is not achievable with Spring MVC.